# Black square blocking lensflare in Three.js

Tags: three.js, webvr, gear-vr

In Oculus VR browser (Samsung Gear VR), when a plane with png(alpha channel) texture in front of lensflare or a object block parts of lensflare, the lensflare become a black square. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Does the [lensflares example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lens#webgl_lensflares) work on the phone when not in a VR headset?

Comment: What sort of Material is on the plane? I don't think the three.js materials take into account the alpha channel of a png.

Comment: Yes @TheJim01, it is only happening in VR browser and only for Oculus one. No such problem in Samsung Internet VR browser.

Comment: @2pha [They do indeed!](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=blend#webgl_materials_blending) It's much more efficient to draw a chain-link fence using a plane with an alpha texture, rather than a bunch of geometries/lines. **axaq:** If a different browser on the same phone can handle the example, then it's definitely a problem with the Oculus browser.

Comment: @TheJim01, ahh ok, I was just remembering a project I worked on where I had to alter the phongmaterial to take into account the alpha channel of a png applied to the map channel. Though that was about 5 years back.

Comment: Thanks guys and yes @2pha it is actually an old issue which has been fixed years ago for most common browsers but since VR browsers are quite new, I think it kind of resurrected because of the way they handle rendering. Actually mrdoob just responded me on git saying that this may be fixed in the next three.js version(90).